# Why does my fivem code reads the if statement first then the MySQL.Async.fetchAll?

Tags: mysql, database, lua, fivem

Hi guys i am trying to remove money from a database (updating it with a new value) when i buy an upgrade for my vehicle. However the code just doenst work because he first reads the if statement and only after the MySQL.Async.fetchAll. I hope somebody can help me and explain me why......................

```
AddEventHandler('Mechanic:PayModifications', function(preco,id,vehprops)
    local config = Config.TunningLocations[id]
    local _source = source
    local pago = false
    local xPlayer = ESX.GetPlayerFromId(_source)
    local societyAccount

    if config.used == _source then
        local permitido = true
        if config.job then
            permitido = false
            if xPlayer.getJob().name == config.job then
                permitido = true
            end
        end
        if permitido then
            if config.society and config.job then

                MySQL.Async.fetchAll("SELECT money FROM t1ger_mechanic WHERE shopID = @shopID", {['@shopID'] = '1'}, function(data)
                    if data[1].money ~= nil then 
                        societyAccount = data[1].money
                    end
        
                    print(societyAccount)           
                    local newmoney = (societyAccount - preco)           
                    print(newmoney)         
        
                    if societyAccount >= preco then 
                        pago = true
                        MySQL.Async.execute('UPDATE t1ger_mechanic SET money = money WHERE  shopID = @shopID', { ['@shopID'] = shopID, ['@money'] = newmoney })
                    end
                end)

            end
    end

    print(pago)

    if pago then
        print("sucesso")
        SaveVehicle(vehprops)
        if Config.WebHook and Config.WebHook ~= "" then
            sendToDiscord('Mechanic Upgrade/Tuning Logs', "[Upgrade/Tuning Logs]\n\nTotal: ".. preco .."\n\nVehicle Plate Number: [".. vehprops.plate .."]\nMechanic that worked on the vehicle: " .. xPlayer.name, 11750815)
        end
    end
    TriggerClientEvent("Bennus:PayAfter",_source,pago)
end)
```

Comment: There are lots of `if` statements, which one are you talking about?

Comment: If you mean `if pago`, that's because the SQL query runs asynchronously. Everything that depends on the result needs to be in the callback function. The `if` statement is outside the callback, so it doesn't wait for the query to complete.

Comment: It says it right there in the function name: `MySQL.Async.fetchAll`

Answer (score 0):

The function `MySQL.Async.fetchAll` is asynchronous, so your code is not waiting for a response from the query before executing the code below.

What you should do, is move everything into the callback function as shown below:

```
MySQL.Async.fetchAll("SELECT money FROM t1ger_mechanic WHERE shopID = @shopID", {['@shopID'] = '1'}, function(data)
    if data[1].money ~= nil then 
       societyAccount = data[1].money
    end
end)
```

That should do the job.